# angularjs update paging after filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of data that is filtered and then paged. It's displayed with `md-virtual-repeat`. I need to update the `totalPages` after each search so that the appropriate paging is applied when a search happens. This is what I have for the search box:

```
<input data-onyx-textbox="search" ng-model="$ctrl.searchInput" style="width:60%;" ng-change="$ctrl.updatePgSize()"
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default':500, 'blur':0 } }" placeholder="search" />
```

Here is the display

```
<div md-virtual-repeat-container>
    <div md-virtual-repeat="s in $ctrl.filtered = ($ctrl.schedules | filter:{name:$ctrl.searchInput}) | startFrom:($ctrl.currentPage-1)*$ctrl.pageSize | limitTo:$ctrl.pageSize">
            <span>{{ s.name }}</span>
            <span>{{ s.length }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have in the controller that updates the `totalPages`

```
public updatePgSize = () => {
     this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.filtered.length/this.pageSize);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the search box is altered `ng-change` gets called immediately before the filters are applied and `filtered` changes. So if the original array had 30 elements, in the first call of the `updatePgSize` function it would think `filtered` also had 30 elements since the actual filtered hasn't run yet. How can I make it so that the `updatePgSize` method gets called after the filtering? I've considered adding a delay but that isn't an efficient fix to the problem.